# Downloading a song through python-requests

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2

I was trying to make a script to download songs from internet. I was first trying to download the song by using "requests" library. But I was unable to play the song. Then, I did the same using "urllib2" library and I was able to play the song this time.

Can't we use "requests" library to download songs? If yes, how?

Code by using requests:

```
import requests
doc = requests.get("http://gaana99.com/fileDownload/Songs/0/28768.mp3")
f = open("movie.mp3","wb")
f.write(doc.text)
f.close()
```

Code by using urllib2:

```
import urllib2
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen("http://gaana99.com/fileDownload/Songs/0/28768.mp3")
output = open('test.mp3','wb')
output.write(mp3file.read())
output.close()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `doc.content` to save [binary data](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

```
import requests

doc = requests.get('http://gaana99.com/fileDownload/Songs/0/28768.mp3')
with open('movie.mp3', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(doc.content)
```

**Explanation**

A MP3 file is only binary data, you cannot retrieve its *textual* part. When you deal with plain text, `doc.text` is ideal, but for any other binary format, you have to access bytes with `doc.content`.

You can check the used encoding, when you `get` a plain text response, `doc.encoding` is set, else it is empty:

```
>>> doc = requests.get('http://gaana99.com/fileDownload/Songs/0/28768.mp3')
>>> doc.encoding
# nothing

>>> doc = requests.get('http://www.example.org')
>>> doc.encoding
ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar way from [here](https://kodlogs.com/84094/python-download-file-from-url-and-save):

```
import urllib.request 
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://gaana99.com/fileDownload/Songs/0/28768.mp3', 'movie.mp3')
```